# GA: Can Unique Screen/Page Views be combined with Hit-level Custom Dimensions?

Tags: google-analytics

I take it from [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1257084#pageviews_vs_unique_views) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636007/google-analytics-unique-pageview-vs-visits) thread that unique screen/pageviews are hit-level based.

Hence, custom dimensions with hit-level scope and unique views should be combinable. However, if I create a custom report with unique views as a metric and custom dimensions of scope hit and page/screen name there are zero to hardly any unique views listed. Is this bevhavior to be expected?

Here is an example:

[image: Example Setup for Custom Report]
The dimensions represent a publication and an issue of that publication. The screen name is restricted to those, where the custom dimensions are set. The same applies to the custom dimensions.

The result looks as follows:
[image: GA Custom Report Results with false Unique Views]
There are regular screen views, but hardly any unique ones.

Is that to be expected? Does that mean that the custom dimensions are not set properly (from debugging I'd say they are set correctly)?